# How to write a nested loop with an increasing counter using list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I'm trying to optimize my code by avoiding nested loops and using list comprehension in python 3. I'll give you a simplified version of my problem using nested loops. Let's say that I have the following two lists:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Then, I need to get the following list of lists:

```
[['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae'],
 ['bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be'],
 ['cc', 'cd', 'ce'],
 ['dd', 'de'],
 ['ee']]
```

Note that I'm trying to avoid to perform duplicate operations. That is, I don't want to get `'ba'`, `'ca'`, etc., because, for instance, `'ab'` is equal to `'ba'` in my problem.

I got this already using a nested loop structure as follows:

```
outerlist = []
i = 0
for el1 in list1:
    innerlist = []
    for el2 in list2[i:]:
        innerlist.append(el1+el2)
    i += 1
    outerlist.append(innerlist)
```

I've profiled my code and this is not very efficient computationally. For this reason, I want to use list comprehension.

I know that using list comprehension I can get all the combinations as follows (there are several questions about this):

```
[i+j for i in list1 for j in list2]
```

Which gives me:

```
['aa','ab','ac','ad','ae','ba','bb','bc','bd','be','ca','cb','cc','cd','ce','da','db','dc','dd','de','ea','eb','ec','ed','ee']
```

But again, I don't want "repeated" combinations (`'ab' = 'ba'`, `'de' = 'ed'` and so on), and more importantly, I don't want to calculate `b+a`if I already have `a+b`.

Since I need to do this millions of times using very long lists, I'm looking for the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

With *"offset"* magic (the *ordinal* position of the item from `list1` becomes an offset for slicing `list2` to avoid duplicate combinations):

```
res = [[v1 + v2 for v2 in list2[i - 1:]] for i, v1 in enumerate(list1, 1)]
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae'],
 ['bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be'],
 ['cc', 'cd', 'ce'],
 ['dd', 'de'],
 ['ee']]
```